# Calendar icon is went missing in Skype for Business 2015

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, skype, lync-2013

[calendar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PwVq.png)
is missing in Lync AKA Skype for Business 2015.

Windows 7 64bit enterprise. Part of Office 2013.

Steps I tried:

1. Cleaned Lync cache "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync"
2. Reinstalled Lync.
3. Restarted Laptop.
4. Office repair.